# consulta en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy haciendo una funcion como esta:

```
function cantidadDePreguntas(cantidad){
            for(let x=1; x<cantidad; x++){
                console.log(x);
                $(".button_test"+x).click(function(e){
                    if($(this).val()=="true"){
                      si=si+1;  
                      }else{no=no+1;}
                    $('#modal'+x).modal('toggle');
                    //console.log(x);
                    var abrirsiguienteModal=x+1;
                    //console.log(abrirsiguienteModal);
                    $('#modal'+abrirsiguienteModal).modal({backdrop: false});
                 })
    
            }
            
        }
cantidadDePreguntas(15);
```

No entiendo porque la x a partir del $(".button_test"+x).click(function(e){  solo recorre hasta el numero 3 no más, alguna sugerencia. Saludos

Comment: Muéstranos el código html donde tienes los elementos `.button_test1`, `.buton_test2`, `.button_test_3`... Es que lo haces con un selector de clase (con el punto delante) en lugar de selector de diferentes ids, y se me hace raro. Por otro lado... ¿cuántos modals tienes definidos por html? ¿Has hecho hasta 15, por ejemplo?

Comment: HOla mil gracias por ressponder, si ese era el error que tenia, no habia actualizado los numeros de los solo tenia hasta el 4 .button_test

Comment: Me alegro de que vaya bien. El tema es que aún así... cuando haces muchos modals, lo normal es que puedas hacer uno sólo y cambiar lo que convenga antes de abrirlo (contenido del interior, programación al aceptar/cerrarlo...). Especialmente si el código es prácticamente igual para todos. Pero bueno, eso ya es una decisión tuya dependiendo de necesidades y todo eso.

Comment: ah ok lo voy a intentar, si me gustaría optimizarlo